# How to check the ipV6 address in selenium with java?

Tags: java

Application is displaying Ipv6 address. My selenium project checks the IP using the code 
`dataValid=IntegerValidator.getInstance().isValid("<<IP>>");` 
but this returns the `IPV4` so the test is failing. I need to return the `IPV6` .

I tried `isValidInet6Address(String inet6Address)` method but

```
The method isValidInet6Address(String) is undefined for the type InetAddressValidator
```

error is displayed

Answer (score 1):

Please try using InetAddressUtils from httpclient library:

```
import org.apache.http.conn.util.InetAddressUtils;

public class TestIp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println(InetAddressUtils.isIPv6Address("2001:cdba:0000:0000:0000:0000:3257:9652")); //true
        System.out.println(InetAddressUtils.isIPv6Address("2001:cdba::3257:9652")); //true
        System.out.println(InetAddressUtils.isIPv6Address("2001:cdba:0:0:0:0:3257:9652")); //true
        System.out.println(InetAddressUtils.isIPv6Address("185.23.56.32")); //false
        System.out.println(InetAddressUtils.isIPv4Address("192.168.0.5")); //true
        System.out.println(InetAddressUtils.isIPv4Address("2001:cdba:0:0:0:0:3257:9652")); //false

    }

}
```